# Retrieve content from JSON nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON response that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "alias": "Server1", 
        "hostgroup_worst_service_state": "0", 
        "status_history": {
            "status": [
                "0", 
                "2", 
                "0", 
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "alias": "Server2", 
        "hostgroup_worst_service_state": "0", 
        "status_history": {
            "status": [
                "0", 
                "0", 
                "0", 
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "alias": "Server3", 
        "hostgroup_worst_service_state": "0", 
        "status_history": {
            "status": [
                "1", 
                "1", 
                "1", 
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I can easily access the alias and hostgroup_worst_state using the .each iterator function:

```
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
   console.log(item.alias)
   console.log(item.hostgroup_worst_service_state)
}
```

However I struggle to have access to the status data. I would need to display them this way:

```
["0","2","0","0"]
["0","0","0","0"]
["1","1","1","1"]
```

These value will next be used to display graphs using jQuery Sparklines.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Hum. Did you look at the many related questions ? If so, what's the problem ?

Comment: does `item.status_history.status` not give you an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of objects, where each object has a property called `status_history`, which points to another object that has a property called `status`, which contains your required array. Thus, to access this array, use the following:

```
$.each(data, function () { 
  console.log(this.status_history.status); 
});
```

Note that `this` inside `.each()` refers to *each* object/value you iterate. It's the equivalent of using the following:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) { 
  console.log(item.status_history.status); 
});
```

Also, if you want an array of arrays with the given status data, you could use `$.map()`:

```
var arr = $.map(data, function (el) { 
  return [ el.status_history.status ];
});
```

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks. I was on the right way but my error was somewhere else. However thumbs up for the explanation. It cleared my doubts and solve my problem to some extend.

Answer (score 1):

**Result** will contain the required arrays.

```
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    result.push(data[i].status_history.status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take your data to an element , say data
then

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 console.log(data.status_history.status);
}
```